# Blank Launcher in Menu Bar in 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, launcher, metacity

I recently upgraded my desktop from 16.04 to 22.04. Under Gnome 3 (Metacity) I now have a blank Launcher on the right end of my menu bar, to the left of the Indicator applet, as shown:

[image]

The Properties dialog for this launcher is blank, and the mouseover text reads `Failed to load key file "/home/<userid>/.config/gnome-panel/launchers/firefox-2.desktop": No such file or directory`.

How can I get rid of this superfluous Launcher?

Comment: `Alt `+ `Right click` -> Remove from panel

Comment: Thank you. I had visions of digging through infinite system folders. Will you post this as an answer?